# css button image not loading in combination with id and style class

Tags: java, css, javafx-8, fxml

I'm migrating my Java 7 app to Java 8 and noticed a strange behavior. Explanation in short:

I have a button defined in FXML with **style class** `button-red-big` and **id** `btnInput`:

```
<Button id="btnInput" fx:id="btnInput" alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle_InputButton" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="button-red-big" text="%experthome.button.input" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
```

When users go over the red button with their mouse, it turns white. This is set by CSS with following code:

```
.button-red-big {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(207,28,0);
    -fx-background-radius: 6, 5;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.4) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.button-red-big:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(207,28,0);
}

.button-red-big:pressed {
    -fx-padding: 10 15 13 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 0 0,2 0 3 0, 2 0 4 0, 2 0 5 0;
}
```

To make it more fancier, I added an image to that button. When the button is in normal state, the button has a red background (as shown in the css above) and a white image. When the button is in hover state, it has a white background and a red image.

The images are applied by css based on the **id** and the **style class** of the button like this:

```
#btnInput .button-red-big {
    -fx-background-image: url("/src/img/Input_w.png"); //white image
}

#btnInput .button-red-big:hover {
    -fx-background-image: url("/src/img/Input_r.png"); //red image
}
```

This used to work perfectly in Java 7. However, in Java 8, the image is not getting loaded. Now, if I add the `-fx-background-image` line straight away in the `.button-big-red`, the image gets loaded normally... But that is not the ideal solution because I have different images (linked to red buttons) like this:

```
#btnAnalysis .button-red-big {
    -fx-background-image: url("/src/img/Analysis_w.png");
}

#btnAnalysis .button-red-big:hover {
    -fx-background-image: url("/src/img/Analysis_r.png");
}

#btnOutput .button-red-big {
    -fx-background-image: url("/src/img/Output_w.png");
}

#btnOutput .button-red-big:hover {
    -fx-background-image: url("/src/img/Output_r.png");
}
```

I hope my explanation is a bit clear. Any ideas what may cause this behavior?

Comment: Is the text color change still being applied on hover?

Comment: Yes everything is working as before except the loading of the image

Comment: Are you by any chance using Eclipse Kepler?

Comment: Also, try omitting the first slash in the relative filepath. There was a bug in JavaFX CSS parsing for the longest time related to that.

Comment: @TylerH: I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2. I also tried to play with the paths. I removed the slash, tried with `./` and `../` but it all had the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect.

```
#btnAnalysis .button-red-big { ... }
```

will select nodes with css class `button-red-big` that are descendants (in the scene graph) of nodes with id `btnAnalysis`.

You probably want just

```
#btnAnalysis { ... }
```

which selects the node with the `btnAnalysis` id, or

```
.button-red-big { ... }
```

which selects nodes with style class `button-red-big`, or even

```
#btnAnalysis.button-red-big { ... }
```

(note no space) which selects nodes with *both* id `btnAnalysis` *and* style class `button-red-big`.

Comment: Hah that a solution can be that easy, I removed the space between the id and the '.' and everything worked again... strange that it did work with the space in Java 7 thou. Thanks a lot James_D!